# Reuse Grails Webflow for mobile and desktop site

Tags: grails

I have a grails webflow that works fine for my desktop browser app.  Now I'd like to reuse the webflow for my mobile site.  I'd prefer not to have 2 separate webflows and just change the pages that are used for each state.  I tried the following:

```
viewState{
    String view = 'viewState'
    boolean isMobile = this.isMobileUser()
    if(isMobile){
        view = "/flowDir/mobile/viewState"
    }       
    render(view:view)       
}
```

However this isn't working.  If the mobile site is accessed first then the desktop will get the mobile pages and vice versa.

Has anyone encountered this problem?  I'd really hate to have 2 webflows that do the same exact thing.  I'd also hate to hack into Sitemesh.  Any ideas or suggestions on how to reuse this flow would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One option is to use Responsive page which renders differently according to the client device and resolution. Look for example to Twitter Boostrap and Responsive functionality. This can be done with css.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the mobile view resolution into an after filter so that your web flow executes the same, but you intercept the view being rendered and rename it.

http://adammonsen.com/post/548

Comment: I like this solution, but the afterInterceptor doesn't seem to be firing.  I wonder if Webflows are handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with droggo that responsive design is the best solution.

However, as an alternative, you could potentially have all webflow users going to the same view, but within that view itself you could override the g:layout taglib with a taglib of your own that is able to determine whether you're running as a mobile user or not, and hence can apply an appropriate layout.

It's maybe a little heavy handed in this context, but it would give you a solution that would be reusable across your entire app, not just within webflow, and it keeps the mobile-specific code in one place.

So in your webflow:

```
viewState{
    String view = 'viewState'
    [snip] The rest of your code goes here     
    render(view:view)       
}
```

Then your view:

```
<myapp:applyLayout name="someWebflowLayout">
    [snip] Your non-layout GSP code goes here    
</myapp:applyLayout>
```

Then your taglib:

```
class MyAppTagLib {
    static namespace = "myapp"

    def applyLayout = { attrs, body ->

        boolean mobileUser = false
        [snip] some logic to determine if this is a mobile user or not goes here

        if (mobileUser) {
            attrs.name = "mobileLayout/${attrs.name}"
        } else {
            attrs.name = "desktopLayout/${attrs.name}"
        }

        out << g.applyLayout(attrs, body)
    }
}
```

You would then have two layout files called someWebflowLayout - one within /layouts/mobileLayout and one within /layouts/desktopLayout (although I appreciate these might not exactly match your existing structure)

The code in the taglib above is only a rough guide, and it'd need bolstering to deal with the other parameters that g:applyLayout takes.